# I have a custom post type with many posts. How do I split the list into multiple pages?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have about 100 posts, and I want to create pages that only show 10 on each. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following query argument: `posts_per_page`

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=10' );
```

Comment: Ok I did that. It shows 10, but how do I get a list of pages now?

Comment: What are you exactly talking about? I thought you want to have a "paged" page template. If you add pagination [1] after the loop, then you can click through your posts (10 per page). [1] http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: added that and got nothing.. hmm

Comment: Please take a look at the "Examples" section at the provided link.

Comment: Ok I think my issue is I'm using WP_Query()

Comment: Yup got it. Cool.